# Why the result of .test() is changing?

Tags: javascript, regex

My code looks like this:

```js
function testfunc() {

  var exp = /aa/gi;

  var ret = [];

  var test = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa'];

  for (var j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {

    ret.push(exp.test(test[j]));

  }

  console.log(ret);

}

testfunc();
```

Instead of returning

```
[true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

it returns

```
[true, false, true, false, true, false]
```

I don't understand why!

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: remo0ve g modifier

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)

Comment: Thank you very much! that post really helped!

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the `g` modifier, because of the [lastIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)

when matching  the next object will start from the last used index instead of `0`

```js
function testfunc() {
  var exp = /aa/i;
  var ret = [];
  var test = ['aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa', 'aaa'];
  for (var j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {
    ret.push(exp.test(test[j]));
  }
  console.log(ret);
}
testfunc();
```